# Does drinking water mitigate the health risks from daily alcohol consumption?

Tags: alcohol, water

Is there any evidence that suggests that the health problems related with the chronic daily over consumption of alcoholic beverages can be mitigated by drinking more water?

Answer (score 3):

The most severe health risk from frequent alcohol consumption are liver damage and malnutrition. There are others, see my list of sources, but I'll focus on those two in my reply.

The *malnutrition* is mostly vitamin deficiencies: folate, vitamin B6, thiamine, and vitamin A. I think it's rather obvious that obvious that consuming more water will not help with those.

As for *liver damage*, that's caused by several things, among them:

- Breakdown of alcohol into [acetaldehyde, which damages the liver](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1360-0443.1988.tb02552.x/abstract)
- Free radicals produced during alcohol metabolism leading to inflammation
- Production of cytokines from this inflammation
- Increase of the passage of toxins produced by bacteria into the liver

These will not be significantly prevented by drinking more water.

Water is good for preventing the short term effects of dehydration that often comes with alcohol intake. It is not enough to prevent the serious effects alcohol can have in the long term.

*Sources*

[Alcohol and the liver](http://pubs.niaaa.nih.gov/publications/aa42.htm)

[Cirrhosis](https://umm.edu/health/medical/altmed/condition/cirrhosis)

[Mechanisms of vitamin deficiencies in alcoholism](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3544907)

[Risks of alcohol misuse](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/alcohol-misuse/pages/risks.aspx)

[Health Risks of Alcohol](http://www.m.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/features/12-health-risks-of-chronic-heavy-drinking)